# Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException in Laravel 10 despite setting timeout to be lower than retry_after

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-queue

I'm using Laravel 10 and PHP 8.1. I have a website monitoring platform which customers can add their websites and they're checked at an interval to see if the sites are up or down. My cron runs every minute.

My Job, `UptimeChecker` seems to be firing a lot of `Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException` exceptions, and I'm wondering what I could be missing to significantly reduce, or get rid of them entirely.

I'm using supervisor, and have 32 workers configured, I'm specifying `--tries=2` on my `php artisan queue:work` command and have set the following in my `UptimeChecker` job:

```php
/**
 * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $timeout = 60;
```

My database connection for the queue is configured like this:

```json
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 180,
    'after_commit' => false,
],
```

Since retry_after is 180, and my timeout is 60, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error?

> Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\UptimeChecker has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:780

Comment: MaxAttempsExceed is just an indication that your jobs is failing after hitting the maximum retry limit (Imagine if it throws an exception immediately) . It is not correlated to timeout or retry_after which is settings to control when the job will retry often from a crashed state or long running state